two surfaces in $P^6$
Let $P^6$ be the complex projective space of dimension $6$, and $X\cong P^2$ and $Y\cong P^3$ be a projective plane and a 3-dimensional space in generic position, i.e., $X\cap Y=\emptyset$. Let $C\subset X$ and $D\subset Y$ be normal rational curves in $X$ and $Y$, respectively, and $f\colon C\longrightarrow D$ be an isomorphism. Let $Z$ be the union of all lines through $x$ and $f(x)$, for all $x\in C$. As far as I understand, $Z$ is a surface isomorphic to $P^1\times P^1$ (is this true ?). Finally, let $g$ be a projective automorphism of $P^6$ (induced by a linear transformation of a linear space, whose projectivization is $P^6$).
I am interested in, what the intersection $Z\cap g(Z)$ may be ? Say, if this intersection is finite, how many points it may has ? If it is of dimension $1$, how many components of dimension $1$ it has, and what these components are (lines, rational curves, non-rational curves) ?
I almost do not know algebraic geometry. So, I would also ask, which textbook may be most suitable for attempts to solve the question above by myself ? Have I to read Hartshorne, or Shafarevich, or something more elementary like Reid's "Undergraduate AG" may be sufficent?

Z is a Hirzebruch surface F_1, the projectivization of O + O(1) on P^1

The threefold $Z$ can be written as
$$
Z = \mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(\mathcal{O}(2) \oplus \mathcal{O}(3))
$$
i.e., it is a rational surface scroll of type $(2,3)$ (because one of your curves is a conic and the other is a cubic). As an abstract surface it is the Hirzebruch surface $\mathbb{F}_1$.
Since $\mathrm{codim}(Z) = 4 > 2 = \dim(Z)$, for a general $g$ the intersection $Z \cap g(Z)$ is empty. To classify all possible non-transverse intersections is tricky.
